# Performing OAUth Authentication within android

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-play-services

I have scanned as much info as I can concerning this and came across this

```
WARNING:Google Play services is required to compile and run this sample. It will launch soon. Please check on https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services for more details. For now, we have provided a dummy google-play-services.jar that only compiles the sample but will not run correctly.

Android application registration: You first need to register your Android application and sign up for access to the Google Calendar API in the Google APIs Console. First, you need the "Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)" for the debug and release builds:
```

I would like to know is this has become available and if not I there is another way through which I can access the google APIs effectively. Also I will really appreciate it if I could get very good step by step resources to accomplishing this.
And please the sample codes downloaded aren't working,I have tried several times to no avail. Would it be better stick to an older versions or use client login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) APIs are not available yet. You can have a look at some [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-preview-android-sample/?repo=samples&name=default) using those APIs but you won't be able to run them as you would need the services to be installed on your phone.

In the meantime, you could use the `AccountManager` to retrieve anonymous OAuth 2.0 tokens as documented in this [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-google-tasks-api-and-oauth-20-on.html); but keep in mind that using this technique won't work with the Google Drive API as the `?key=` query parameter is no longer supported.

Comment: The Google Play Services are now available